# Wrapping a 2D net over a 3D object

Tags: modeling, modifiers, physics

Is there a way to have a 2D mesh wrapped around a 3D object. Like this:
[image: Knot wrapped around 3D object]

The red part is a flattened knot, which I mapped onto the surface of the blue part. In this specific case I used math to achieve it, but not all shapes can be easily expressed as formulae. What other ways are there?

I tried using physics, making the blue part a passive rigid body and the red part a soft body falling onto the blue part, and it seemed to work beautifully. But when I tried it again now, I realised that it doesn't do what I'm after. The net and the object onto which I want to wrap it already have the same X and Y dimensions, which is how I want it. I only need to remap the Z coordinates.

Another idea that comes to mind, would be generating a texture from the Z coordinates of the blue part and use that texture with the displace modifier on the red part. Is this possible?

Comment: use shrink wrap modifier?

Comment: I honestly didn't think of that one. I tried it just now, and it doesn't do exactly what I need. And had to look again at what the physics does, and it actually fails in the same way. I didn't close enough the first time, because I couldn't find a way to get it to remain. Both curve the object, so that the vertices move along all axes, not just the Z.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a conbination of **Mesh Deform** and **Cloth simulation** with proper settings.

- Create a grid plane to cover the whole net;
- Add **Cloth** Simulator to it, then **Solidify** modifier;
- Tweak settings of them;
- Add **Mesh Deform** modifier to the net object. (use higher *Presision* value if necessary, then *Band*)
- Then play or bake the final shape. Delete the grid mesh (optional).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**[Example File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ojv5B6Lb-3VGdkbndkLXNITlU/view?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Thank you for that. Where I am, it is currently so late that it's actually early, and I'm off to bed. I will try this out when I wake up.

Comment: I upvoted and accepted your answer. It does change the X and Y coordinates as the net wraps around the collider, but it certainly feels like it gives me more control than the shrinkwrap, suggested in a comment to my question, especially in the case where I bevel the net before wrapping it. Thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: Sure. You can also do manual control instead of simulation (In that case, a Lattice modifier works better). I believe both leave you a lot of flexablility. :)